# Python - exception handler isn't executed

Tags: python, argparse

I don't know why, but cislo is still 10, when i print it on the end of program, so exception handler isn't executed, but i am sure exception was raised.

```
import argparse
import locale
import sys

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'cs_CZ.UTF-8')

cislo = 10

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='dka', description="Determinizace konecneho automatu(DKA)")
parser.add_argument("--inputs", help='vstupni soubor', default=sys.stdin)

try:
    parser.parse_args(['--input', 'agas', '--input', 'agag'])
except argparse.ArgumentError:
    cislo = 20

print(cislo)
```

Comment: If you put a print inside your except block, does it display?

Comment: How did you confirm that the exception was being raised?

Comment: "but i am sure exception was raised." - why?

Comment: This won't raise an exception; argparse lets you abbreviate `--inputs` as `--input`

Comment: I have excuted your code and the exception **is not raised**, i have put a print "raise exception" and the trace is never printed.

Comment: @Krab if a print inside the `except` block doesn't display, the exception isn't being thrown. Wooble's comment and Pavel's answer cover why.

Comment: yes i see it now, i find on the internet that it should raise exception, so i add exception handler and changed input to inputs, but unlucky this doesn't wrote any error, so i thought exception "dissapear" and handler wasn't executed, fail sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception is not raised for two reasons:

the `--inputs` argument is not required.

```
 parser.add_argument("--inputs", help='vstupni soubor', default=sys.stdin, required=True)
```

the parser accepts `--input` as abbreviated `--inputs` because there's no ambiguity.

Also argparse will not raise ArgumentError, it'll just exit. You could catch SystemExit or subclass ArgumentParser to override this behaviour.

- [The `required` parameter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#required)
- [Argument abbreviations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations)

Comment: hm so i can't return exit code by myself or do some reaction? Really usefull parser :)

Answer (score 1):

Just extend the class then.

```
class myparse(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def exit(self,status,message):
        print("You are bad: ", status, message)
        exit(5)

cislo = 10

parser = myparse(prog='dka', description="Determinizace konecnehoautomatu(DKA)")
```

Gives:

```
usage: dka [-h] [--inputs INPUTS] 
You are bad:  2 dka: error: unrecognized arguments: --inputss agas
```

Comment: thx, but actually there is still problem with that abbrevation(input vs inputs etc.), which is unexpected, so i will parse it by myself